# Converting create table statements from Oracle SQL to PostgreSQL

Tags: database, sql, file-converter, postgresql, oracle-database

I am looking for a program that can converting create table statements from Oracle SQL to PostgreSQL (e.g., choose the closest type for each column).

Any OS, any license, any price is fine. CLI or GUI.

Comment: I haven't found any tool so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.